# How to "hard code" a pie chart in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Small question regarding how to "hard code" a pie chart using Tableau please.

By "hard code", I mean I have no data set for the pie chart itself.

I have some data where I built workbook and visuals already.

This hard coded pie chart does not come from any data set, it is more like an extra visual information I would like to add to the overall work book.

Is it possible to just hard code something like this please?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to create a static pie chart like the one below, you can follow the steps here. But bear in mind I did need to have SOME initial data in my workbook so that I could hardcode my "Success/Failure" string values --> you would need to at least have 1 string dimension in your worksheet so you can replicate the steps here.

[image]

1. **Create a Calculated Field that will produce the "Success/Failure" values you need.**
   I created an IF/ELSE Calculated Field based on an existing string Dimension.

In this case I based the calculations on the Region dimension. If the Region dimension had a specific (dummy) value, my Calculated field would give me a "Success" value, and a "Failure" value if the Region field did not contain such dummy value.

You can use any dimension that you want in your Calculated field calculation, and you could even use one that already has the Success/Failure values in the dimension (so you could skip having to create a Calculated Field to produce such values).

[image]

2. Once I had created my Success/Failure values, I created a Calculated Field (HardCodeValues_pieChart) that would assign a 7 to any rows containing a "Failure" and a 32 to rows with a "Success" value (this is based on your example where you had already provided 7 and 32 for the values in the pie chart).

[image]

3. I used my HardCodeValues_pieChart calculated field in the Angle mark card of my pie chart, making sure I was using the Average values of the calculated field.